# Openquery SQL how to check if exists?

Tags: sql-server-2008, openquery

I am using sql `OPENQUERY` to check if record exist passing parameter update it, if not insert a new record.

Here is what I have so far

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR (8000)
DECLARE @Id VARCHAR(20)

SET @Id= '31124'

SET @sql = '
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY
(
   SERVERNAME, 
   ''
   SELECT Name FROM table WHERE Id= ''''' + @Id +  ''''' 
   ''
)'
EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR (8000)
DECLARE @Id VARCHAR(20)

SELECT @Id= '31124'

SELECT @sql =
'
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY
    (
        SERVERNAME, 
        ''SELECT Name FROM table WHERE Id= ''''' + @Id +  '''''''
    )
) 
BEGIN  
    UPDATE OPENQUERY
    (
        SERVERNAME, 
        ''SELECT Name FROM table WHERE Id= ''''' + @Id +  '''''''
    )   
    SET Name = ''NewName''
ELSE
    INSERT OPENQUERY
    (
        SERVERNAME, 
        ''SELECT Name FROM table''
    )   
    VALUES
    (
        ''NewName''
    )
END 
'

EXEC (@sql)
```

---

Unless you have some specific requirement to use `EXEC`, you don't need it.

```
DECLARE @Id VARCHAR(20)

SELECT @Id= '31124'

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY
    (
        SERVERNAME, 
        'SELECT Name FROM table WHERE Id= ''' + @Id +  ''''
    )
) 
BEGIN  
    UPDATE OPENQUERY
    (
        SERVERNAME, 
        'SELECT Name FROM table WHERE Id= ''' + @Id +  ''''
    )   
    SET Name = 'NewName'
ELSE
    INSERT OPENQUERY
    (
        SERVERNAME, 
        'SELECT Name FROM table'
    )   
    VALUES
    (
        'NewName'
    )
END
```